# Is Generator class need for ID tag in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, triggers

I am new to Hibernate and question is "Is Generator class need for ID tag in Hibernate?"

In my table have trigger mentioned below and my table is existing table and having records.Just I did code change from Native SQL to Hibernate session. in this case "Is Generator class need for ID tag in Hibernate? or not" . Here my exception is record need to insert with next sequence value.

```
TRIGGER TRG_BI_APPLICATION_DATA_LOCK
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON APPLICATION_DATA_LOCK REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   exception_no_null_pk   EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   IF :new.APP_DATA_LOCK_ID is null
   THEN
     SELECT SEQ_APPLICATION_DATA_LOCK_PK.nextval
        INTO :new.APP_DATA_LOCK_ID
        FROM dual;
   END IF;
END;
```

Assuming before insert call trigger will create next ID value and insert will happen. So, in hbm file, we need generator class or if we need means which generator have to use? 
Please help me in this regard...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to infer what you are asking from your question title and the answer to that is no, you don't need a @GeneratedValue annotation for your ID to work, only if you want to specify that a) your ID is going to be a value not generated by Hibernate, and b) if you want to specify how your ID is going to be generated.

I think what you need to do is this:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Foo{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "applicationLockSequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "applicationLockSequence" sequenceName = "SEQ_APPLICATION_DATA_LOCK_PK")
    private int id;
 ....
}
```

This basically specifies that there is a sequence on the database with that name, and that Hibernate should use that sequence to assign your object an ID when it gets saved. There is no need to do this at a database level with a trigger, although that is also a valid method. If you want to do it with a trigger, just leave out `@GeneratedValue` and `@SequenceGenerator`.

Hope that answers your question.

TL;DR OP is using a .hbm file for hibernate mappings. 
As given here: [How To Use Sequence In Hibernate As A Property In XML Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082175/how-to-use-sequence-in-hibernate-as-a-property-in-xml-mapping)

```
<id name="id" column="item_id>
    <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">SEQ_APPLICATION_DATA_LOCK_PK</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

should be all you need to do this.

Comment: As per your answer, I dont need to use any Generated class in hbm file. write? But, without mentiontion getting following exception:org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): ApplicationDataLock

Comment: Ahh, you are using a hbm file to specify your mapping? I don't think you would need to include a Generated, because the generation of your ID is happening at a database level by your trigger. What it effectively means is that if you ever run into a situation where you need to get the ID of your object, you need to save it to the database then query the database to get your object filled with an ID. All hibernate needs to know is that your object has a field that is its ID, if you don't tell it, it doesn't care how it is generated. Try it and let me know

Comment: If you do want to use your sequence without using a trigger then use the following config given in the link in your hbm file.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082175/how-to-use-sequence-in-hibernate-as-a-property-in-xml-mapping

Comment: Doing a bit of further reading, this method would be preferable to using a database trigger. This method lets hibernate handle your id generation before its saved to the database, which is a computationally cheaper option that running that trigger every time a new record is entered into your table.

Comment: I have refered stackoverflow.com/questions/5082175/… used like below but getting 12:21:15.916 [main] DEBUG o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - could not get next sequence value [select SEQ_APPLICATION_DATA_LOCK_PK.nextval from dual]
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Comment: But its select SEQ_APPLICATION_DATA_LOCK_PK.nextval from dual working in DB editor.. not in application.

Comment: I just want to know how Natvie SQL(createSQLQuery) generating/Inserting the same ID value as we are not inserting/providing.

Comment: `<id name="id" column="item_id>
   <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">SEQ_APPLICATION_DATA_LOCK_PK</param>
    </generator>
</id>`
Don't use a select statement in your block, you only have to give Hibernate the name of your sequence. You don't have to use native SQL to insert an ID, if hibernate knows where to get your ID from, it will do all that for you. If this still doesn't work can you post an entire stacktrace in your question, along with your hbm file and container class?